# How to add one-to-many relationships in Sql Azure .NET using code first?

Tags: sql, azure, entity-framework-4, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

I'm working on an Azure Mobile Service and I want to create a one to many relationship in Azure SQL. For example if a Project has many Areas.

The code I'm using is:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace AzureService.DataObjects
{
    public class Project : EntityData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Area> Areas { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace AzureService.DataObjects
{
    public class Area : EntityData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ShapeFile { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Scenario> Scenarios { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Id")]
        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to do it?

Comment: That should work. Did you try and have any problems with it?

Comment: Yeah, when I go to test it it returns a 500 error response. So is there another class specific to Azure for collections instead of ICollection?

Comment: Also, where can I find relationships documented? I'm finding it hard to find them with a search.

Comment: The posts at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/05/27/how-to-expand-linked-entities-from-mobileservices-client-and-mobileservices-service.aspx (reading data in 1:n) and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/06/18/insert-update-related-data-with-1-n-relationship-using-net-backend-azure-mobile-services.aspx (inserting / update data in 1:n) talk about this scenario on the .NET runtime, those should be a good starting point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct implementation is like so:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Mobile.Service;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace AzureService.DataObjects
{
    public class Project : EntityData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Area> Areas { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace AzureService.DataObjects
{
    public class Area : EntityData
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ShapeFile { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Scenario> Scenarios { get; set; }

        public string ProjectId { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public virtual Project Project { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Like mentioned in the comments more information can be found at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/azuremobile/archive/2014/05/27/how-to-expand-linked-entities-from-mobileservices-client-and-mobileservices-service.aspx.